# Load soap response to UIWebview Issue-iPhone

Tags: iphone, uiwebview

I want to show the soap response to UIWebview..

**my soap response is,**

> <p><img src="http://img.gawkerassets.com/img/17u1vg3xyeuipjpg/xlarge.jpg" width="410" data-size="large"/></p><p><a rel="lytebox" href="http://img.gawkerassets.com/img/17u1vg3xyeuipjpg/original.jpg"> <a href="http://img.gawkerassets.com/img/17u1vg3xyeuipjpg/original.jpg" rel="modal"></a> <p></a>Before sharing a playlist of songs with a crush was as simple as a few clicks, the mixtape was a labour of love; a time-consuming project. Every song was carefully considered. That&#8217;s all gone now, of course, but this DIY MP3 player conjured up by MakerBot can help bring it back.<img src="http://feeds.feedburner.com/r/GizmodoAustralia/4/zFs-k-3__1I" height="1" width="1"/>

like above..

am using this code for load the soap response to UIWebview

```
[webView loadHTMLString:soapresponse baseURL:nil];
```

in webview i want to clear the tags and display the contents.

anyone please help me to do this..

Thank you

Comment: Are you getting text into your variable or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT** Decoding HTML entities like & lt;  to < : use [NSString+HTML](https://github.com/mwaterfall/MWFeedParser/blob/master/Classes/NSString+HTML.m)

```
NSString *strEncodeHTML = @"&lt;p&gt;&lt;img src=&quot;img.gawkerassets.com/img/17u1vg3xyeuipjpg/xlarge.jpg&quot; width=&quot;410&quot; data-size=&quot;large&quot;/&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;&lt;a rel=&quot;lytebox&quot; href=&quot;img.gawkerassets.com/img/17u1vg3xyeuipjpg/…; &lt;a href=&quot;img.gawkerassets.com/img/17u1vg3xyeuipjpg/original.jpg&quot; rel=&quot;modal&quot;&gt;&lt;/a&gt; &lt;p&gt;&lt;/a&gt;content here.img src=&quot;feeds.feedburner.com/r/GizmodoAustralia/4/zFs-k-3__1I&quot; height=&quot;1&quot; width=&quot;1&quot;/&gt;";

strEncodeHTML = [[[strEncodeHTML stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&lt;" withString:@"<"] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&gt;" withString:@">"] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&quot;" withString:@"\""];
NSLog(@"%@",strEncodeHTML);
NSString *strHTML = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html><body>%@<body></html>",strEncodeHTML] ;

[webView loadHTMLString:strHTML baseURL:nil];
```

---

Load html content like this:

```
NSString *strHTML = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html><body>%@</html>/<body>",yourSoapresponse];

[webView loadHTMLString:strHTML baseURL:nil];
```

Below given is example:

```
NSString *strHTML = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html><body><p><img src=\"http://img.gawkerassets.com/img/17u1vg3xyeuipjpg/xlarge.jpg\" width=\"410\" data-size=\"large\"/></p><p><a rel=\"lytebox\" href=\"http://img.gawkerassets.com/img/17u1vg3xyeuipjpg/original.jpg\"> <a href=\"http://img.gawkerassets.com/img/17u1vg3xyeuipjpg/original.jpg\" rel=\"modal\"></a> <p></a>Before sharing a playlist of songs with a crush was as simple as a few clicks, the mixtape was a labour of love; a time-consuming project. Every song was carefully considered. That&#8217;s all gone now, of course, but this DIY MP3 player conjured up by MakerBot can help bring it back.<img src=\"http://feeds.feedburner.com/r/GizmodoAustralia/4/zFs-k-3__1I\" height=\"1\" width=\"1\"/></html>/<body>"];

[webView loadHTMLString:strHTML baseURL:nil];
```

Comment: use https://github.com/mwaterfall/MWFeedParser/blob/master/Classes/NSString+HTML.m to decode to html

Comment: soap response -&lt;p&gt;&lt;img src=&quot;http://img.gawkerassets.com/img/17u1vg3xyeuipjpg/xlarge.jpg&quot; width=&quot;410&quot; data-size=&quot;large&quot;/&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;&lt;a rel=&quot;lytebox&quot; href=&quot;http://img.gawkerassets.com/img/17u1vg3xyeuipjpg/original.jpg&quot;&gt; &lt;a href=&quot;http://img.gawkerassets.com/img/17u1vg3xyeuipjpg/original.jpg&quot; rel=&quot;modal&quot;&gt;&lt;/a&gt; &lt;p&gt;&lt;/a&gt;content here.img src=&quot;http://feeds.feedburner.com/r/GizmodoAustralia/4/zFs-k-3__1I&quot; height=&quot;1&quot; width=&quot;1&quot;/&gt;

Comment: i want to convert the soap response &gt &it to like this <p><img src="http://img.gawkerassets.com/img/17u1vg3xyeuipjpg/xlarge.jpg" width="410" data-size="large"/></p><p><a rel="lytebox" href="http://img.gawkerassets.com/img/17u1vg3xyeuipjpg/original.jpg"> <a href="http://img.gawkerassets.com/img/17u1vg3xyeuipjpg/original.jpg" rel="modal"></a> <p></a> content here. <img src="http://feeds.feedburner.com/r/GizmodoAustralia/4/zFs-k-3__1I" height="1" width="1"/>

Comment: ok. if suppose some new values coming means &amp;#8217; equivalent value is "'" . In this situation what i do?

Comment: your answer is helped me.but, if some new values coming means what may the solution

Comment: use NSString+HTML link in my answer for decoding any kind of value in html.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16014/discussion-between-iphonecool-and-prince)